# Python 3 unicode to utf-8 on file

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to parse through a log file, but the file format is always in unicode. My usual process that I would like to automate:

> - I pull file up in notepad
> - Save as...
> - change encoding from `unicode` to `UTF-8`
> - Then run python program on it

So this is the process I would like to automate in Python 3.4. Pretty much just changed the file to `UTF-8` or something like `open(filename,'r',encoding='utf-8')` although this exact line was throwing me this error when I tried to call read() on it:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

It would be EXTREMELY helpful if I could convert the entire file (like in my first scenario) or just open the whole thing in UTF-8 that way I don't have to str.encode (or something like that) every time I analyze a string.

Anybody been through this and know which method I should use and how to do it?

EDIT:

In the python3 repr, I did

```
>>> f = open('file.txt','r')
>>> f
(_io.TextIOWrapper name='file.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252')
```

So now my python code in my program opens the file with `open('file.txt','r',encoding='cp1252')`. I am running a lot of regex looking through this file though and it isn't picking it up (I think because it isn't utf-8). So I just have to figure out how to switch from cp1252 to UTF-8. Thank you @Mark Ransom

Comment: You need to figure out the encoding that the original file has, and use that instead of `utf-8` when you open the file.

Comment: How do I do that? Because when I hit save as in notepad, it just said unicode

Comment: Alright, I've almost got it! In the python3 repr I figured out that the encoding of the file is cp1252. Now I think I have to just convert that to utf-8 right after opening the file

Comment: Python doesn't analyze the file to figure out which encoding it should use, it just assumes the default for your Windows environment. Notepad on the other hand *does* try to analyze the file. If it says Unicode, it's probably `utf-16le` - try that.

Comment: how do I convert that to utf-8?

Comment: Why do you need to convert? If you open the file with `encoding='utf-16'` you should get proper Unicode strings as you read the file, and your program will "just work".

Comment: It's not. I am writing what I read to another file each time and it is printing characters that look like garbage code. I can't even print out any of it. It says UnicodeEncodeError

Comment: You also need to use `encoding=...` on the file you're writing. They don't need to be the same, and it sounds from what you've said that the output should be utf-8. Don't expect Windows to be able to open a utf-8 file and make sense of it though, that's not its native character set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What notepad considers `Unicode` is `utf16` to Python.  Windows "Unicode" files start with a byte order mark (BOM) of `FF FE`, which indicates little-endian UTF-16.  This is why you get the following when using `utf8` to decode the file:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

To convert to UTF-8, you could use:

```
with open('log.txt',encoding='utf16') as f:
    data = f.read()
with open('utf8.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Note that many Windows editors like a UTF-8 signature at the beginning of the file, or may assume `ANSI` instead.  `ANSI` is really the local language locale.  On US Windows it is `cp1252`, but it varies for other localized builds.  If you open `utf8.txt` and it still looks garbled, use `encoding='utf-8-sig'` when writing instead.