# How to set encoding for files with currency characters in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, ansi

I have ANSI encoded file which has currency characters and after I do some processing in python with content of that file I want to write it to another file, but in resulting file I have e.g. "\u00a3" instead of "£". I tried different combinations of encoding when opening input file and output file but with no success.

Comment: what if you try with `print(u"\u00a3")`

Comment: Can I do it with variable somehow?

Comment: `pound = u"\u00a3"` ?

Comment: What I meant is that I have variable pound="£250.00". And when I write in file there is "\u00a3250.00". When I print it on console it is ok, but in file it is not.

Comment: are you running python in the interpreter, or executing a python `.py` script?

Comment: Running through interpreter

Comment: try `open("output.txt", "w", encoding='utf8')`, src: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463053/python-3-unicode-to-utf-8-on-file

Comment: I managed to solve it. The error was actually that I forgot to set ensure_ascii=False in json.dumps() function. I didn't expect error to be there. Thank you very much, and sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: No worries, glad to hear you solved it and thanks for sharing what you did to get it working. :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try, `open("filename.txt","w", encoding= "ISO-8859-1", errors="ignore")`.

I've tried with utf-8, utf-16 and utf-32, but no use in my case. Then I tried with encoding 'ISO-8859-1' and I'm able to read and write currency symbols. Hope it helps. For more details, check [here](http://blog.conceptnet.io/posts/2012/fixing-common-unicode-mistakes-with-python-after-theyve-been-made/)